# Understanding the use of decrementation in Prolog predicate instead of incrementation?

Tags: list, prolog, logic, increment, predicate

I am new to logical programming and trying to understand a Prolog predicate that involves decrementing a variable, especially the logic behind using decrementation instead of incrementation, but I'm having trouble grasping the concept. The predicate is intended to remove the k-th element from a list.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
sup_k(X, [X|Xs], 1, Xs).
sup_k(X, [Y|Xs], K, [Y|Ys]) :- K > 1, K1 is K - 1, sup_k(X, Xs, K1, Ys).
```

What I don't understand is why the variable K is decremented using K1 is K - 1 instead of incremented. I'm having trouble grasping how this decrementation affects the execution of the predicate and how it helps identify the k-th element to be removed.

Could someone shed some light on the reasoning behind using decrementation in this context? I would appreciate any explanations or insights to help me better understand this concept.

Comment: A disadvantage of this approach is that the `K` integer must be provided to the predicate. My answer doesn't have that restriction. E.g. `sup_k(E, L, N, R).` results in 1 answer, then: `ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`

Comment: "*What I don't understand is why the variable K is decremented using K1 is K - 1 instead of incremented.*" - it's a countdown: three, two, one, GO! Nobody does a countup, three, four, five, six, seven, ..., infinity, infinity+1, infinity+2, ... when would you stop?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler My answer below is counting up ;-)

Comment: @brebs they ask why K is not incremented in their code; your code is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Concepts such as recursion and "base case" are explained [elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=prolog%20recursion%20base%20case).

Can use:

```
% Select at Nth1 position N from list [H|T],
% being element E, with remainder R
select_nth1(N, [H|T], E, R) :-
    (   integer(N)
    ->  N @>= 1
    ;   var(N)
    ),
    % Adding the Upto (U) parameter, counting upwards from 1
    select_nth1_(T, H, 1, N, E, R).

select_nth1_(T, H, U, N, E, T) :-
    (   U == N
    % Determinism 
    ->  !
    % Usual unification
    ;   U = N
    ),
    % Comparing here so the cut takes precedence
    H = E.
% P is the previous Head, added to R
select_nth1_([H|T], P, U, N, E, [P|R]) :-
    % Increment counter
    U1 is U + 1,
    % Loop using tail-end recursion
    select_nth1_(T, H, U1, N, E, R).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- select_nth1(N, [a, b, c, d], E, R).
N = 1,
E = a,
R = [b, c, d] ;
N = 2,
E = b,
R = [a, c, d] ;
N = 3,
E = c,
R = [a, b, d] ;
N = 4,
E = d,
R = [a, b, c].
% No unwanted choicepoint at end, due to [H|T] first-argument indexing

?- select_nth1(2, [a, b, c, d], E, R).
E = b,
R = [a, c, d].
% No unwanted choicepoint at end, due to == and ! determinism
```

In order to understand what's going on here, you will need to learn how to **debug** a Prolog program - use e.g. `trace` and `gtrace` to step through the program, explained at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score -1):

Most recursive problems have 1 or 2 terminating base cases and a general recursive case.

If the object of the exercise is to remove the Kth element, relative to 1, then your base case is "If K is 1, remove the head (1st item in the list)". That's this clause:

```
sup_k( X , [X|Xs] , 1 , Xs     ) .
```

When K is 1, the 1st argument is unified with the head (first item) in the list and the tail (the remaining items in the list) is unified with the last argument.

The general recursive case is "when K is greater than 1, add the ehad of the list to the result, decrement K and recurse on the remainder". That's this clause:

```
sup_k( X , [Y|Xs] , K , [Y|Ys] ) :-
  K > 1,             % if K is greater than 1,
  K1 is K - 1,       % - decrement K
  sup_k(X,Xs,K1,Ys). $ - recurse down on the remainder
  .
```

A lot of the work in a prolog predicate gets done in the head of the clauses. You could rewrite this to make it more clear what's going on like this:

```
sup_k( Kth_item , [X|Xs] , K , Remaining_items ) :- % The kth item can be removed and
    K = 1 ,                                         % - K is equal to 1, and
    Kth_item = X ,                                  % - it unifies with the head of the source list, and
    Remaining_items = Xs                            % - the remaining items unify with the tail of the source list
    .                                               % Easy!
sup_k( Kth_item, [X|Xs] , K , [Y|Ys] ) :-           % Otherwise, 
    K > 1,                                          % If K is greater than 1,
    Y = X ,                                         % - prepend the head of the source list to the result list
    K1 is K - 1,                                    % - decrement K
    sup_k(Kth_item,Xs,K1,Ys)                        % - recurse down, passing K1 and the tails of both source and result lists.
    .                                               % Also easy!
```

Though I might re-write it so as to be more general and not require that you specify a value for K. Something like this: